# Problem with HTML 5 video, the video is not showing

Tags: html, html5-video

so I madean HTML5 video for chrome and firefox ... mp4 and .ogv of course
The problem im having is that the video is working on some chrome browsers while it doesnt on others and the video is not showing at all on any firefox browser ( keep in mind that all browsers that were tested on were fully updated meaning they support HTML5 video ) here is my source code

```
<video id="the-video" width="550px" height="550px" controls>
<source src="videos/intro.mp4"  type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
<source src="videos/intro.ogv"  type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>

</video>
```

Comment: Is your server sending the correct MIME types for the files?

Comment: Maybe this could help you, I'm not sure: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements. A few months ago, I had trouble displaying videos on Firefox, however I could be more recent versions support more formats.

Comment: does this work on your local machine: 
<video src="intro.ogv" controls width="400" height="300" ></video> If the answer is no then the ogv file is not acceptable to firefox. Try http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/ Note Chrome also plays the ogv. Let me also point out that the order of the source does make a difference at least in the beta versions

Comment: i tried the converter it doesnt work .. and i tried the video tag without the sources .. it still doesnt work

Comment: Kay, have you specifically tried it on your local computer ... the reason for this question is troubleshooting. FF does play the video from your local computer unless there is something different in the formatting of the file. ... once it is working on your local computer upload it. If the problem is when it is downloading from an http connection. Go to server support on this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/video ... alternatively you could post a link to get help with the troubleshooting.

Comment: note: htaccess is the easiest way to the correct MIMI type "if" that  is the problem

Comment: yes Wayne, I tried it on my local computer first of course. I'm using MAMP as a local server and I tried to access the local page of course, its still not working ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox doesn't support H.264, [Chrome does but will drop soon](http://www.techtree.com/India/Features/Google_Drops_H264_in_Chrome_What_Does_it_Mean/551-114185-899.html).

Anyway you should use Webm video format for HTML 5.

Comment: Yes but it supports ogg, and should be using that one instead of the mp4.

Answer (score 1):

add *.webm and make it first source

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the .ogv to .ogg, the server might not be set up to serve .ogv files. This has happened me in the past.

Alternatively, if you have access to the server, add the MIME type video/ogg for .ogv extensions.